# Adding to array from multiple foreach statements

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to add the dynamically generated variables `$title` and `$price` to the array `$list`.

This works to a certain degree. The code creates an array with the keys where they have a title and price value.

The price value is correct and different for each key. However, it seems that only the first `title` result is added, creating the following array (same title untill key 30)

```
 [0]=> array(2) { ["title"]=> string(57) "Gibson Les Paul ** Nr.1 Gibson dealer ** 18 gitaarwinkels" ["price"]=> string(25) " € 300,00 " } [1]=> array(2) { ["title"]=> string(57) "Gibson Les Paul ** Nr.1 Gibson dealer ** 18 gitaarwinkels" ["price"]=> string(25) " € 100,00 " }
```

Looking at the code I think it is because the first foreach loop is only executing the second one.

I know the correct values for `$title` are there, because when I isolate the title foreach loop like this:

```
  foreach ($titlehit as $titles) {
  $title = $titles->nodeValue;
  echo "$title";
}
```

30 different `$title` result are displayed

```
$url = "https://url.com";

$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($html);

$titlehit = $xpath->query("//span[@class='mp-listing-title']");
$pricehit = $xpath->query("//span[@class='price-new']");

$list = array();
$i = 0;

  foreach ($titlehit as $titles) {
    foreach ($pricehit as $prices) {
      if ($i >=5 && $i <=35) {
        $title = $titles->nodeValue;
        $price = $prices->nodeValue;
        $list[] = array(
          'title' => $title,
          'price' => $price
          );
        }
      $i++;
    }
  }
```

How can I get the array `$list` to hold both the correct title and price values? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is `$i` used for? as a counter?

Comment: $i is used as a counter to only add results 5->35 to the array. The code before this returns more results.

Comment: @Peter If there is only 30 titles, why are you using magic number 35? Not sure why you need to start at position 5 neither.

Comment: @mickmackusa I've update the code snippet. MaxZoom, I'm retrieving data from a marketplace. The query for this xpath returns 38 results, the first five and last three are sponsored ads. results 5-35 are user listing. Those are what I'm trying to retrieve.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that there are 30 titles, as stated in the question. You loop them and save only from position 5 (which will produce only 26 titles - not 30 as expected), If prices count is different then you will get unreliable results.

Comment: @mickmackusa & maxzoom, your help is much appreciated. I've put the  array which is generated by the code here (https://pastebin.com/kX9ZjHr6). Do you need any more information?

Comment: @mickmackusa (https://pastebin.com/gkEW8H9J) here you go

Comment: @mickmackusa The first five results are unwanted. There seems to be a change to the website I'm scraping from. The last three results now have a different <span> class so aren't being found by the xpath anymore.

Comment: @Peter I've posted an answer that assumes 5 ads at the start and 5 ads at the end of the arrays (the fact that there are actually no ads at the end of your project data will make no difference to my snippet).  I have generated my own test data for my code demo.  I have itemized each aspect of what I consider to be best practices for your task.  If you have questions, leave me a comment and I'll clarify further.

Comment: @Peter I am going to delete my answers on your questions because I lack the necessary depth of knowledge to offer best practices advice.  I would like to urge you to submit a new question that specifically asks for the most refined way to extract your desired values using xpath, and reference your technique.  I believe there are several ways that this can be done with higher efficiency and that is what is truly important (valuable to future readers).

Comment: @mickmackusa, alright. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that for each title, there is one price i.e there is a 1:1 title-to-price ratio in the corresponding arrays, you will only need 1 loop.

```
$list = array();
$i = 0; // initialize
// Assuming $titlehit AND $pricehit have the same number of elements
foreach ($titlehit as $titles) {
    // Assuming $pricehit is a simple array. If it is an associative array, we need to use the corresponding key as the index instead of $i. We'll get to this once you can confirm the input.
    $prices = $pricehit[$i]; 
    // Not entirely sure why you need this condition.
    if ($i >=5 && $i <=35) {
        $title = $titles->nodeValue;
        $price = $prices->nodeValue;
        $list[] = array(
            'title' => $title,
            'price' => $price
        );
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. The $i is used as a counter to make sure only results 5 -> 35 from the previous code get added to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly enough code here to know for sure but it looks like you need to reset your iterator `$i` with each iteration of your `foreach` loop:

```
$list = array();    
  foreach ($titlehit as $titles) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($pricehit as $prices) {
      if ($i >=5 && $i <=35) {
        $title = $titles->nodeValue;
        $price = $prices->nodeValue;
        $list[] = array(
          'title' => $title,
          'price' => $price
          );
        }
      $i++;
    }
  }
```